# List all members in a guild (djs v12)

Tags: dictionary, discord, discord.js

Listing every user in a guild regardless of their Discord Presence.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
 //   if (message.content == "hi") {
   // if (message.author.id !== "ID") return;
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('ID')
    const users = client.users.cache.map((u) => u.id);
      message.guild.members.cache.forEach(members => console.log(users && `Amount of users:`, users.length))
  
      console.log(`Listing user ids from ${guild.name}:`);
      console.log(users);
      console.log(users.length)
  //  }
  });
```

My current code does not list users in the guild ID I provided, the bot is in the server. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) doesn't use `length` but [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size) instead. So in order to list everyone in a guild, you could do something like this:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.author.bot === true) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    // Trigger with 'list all members'
    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === "list all members") {
        // Get the guild from Cache using the GuildID from the message
        // Or manually put in the ID from the server your bot is in.
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id);

        // Force member cache to be cleared and renewed.
        await guild.members.fetch({ force: true });

        // Map all users.
        console.log(`Listing ${guild.members.cache.size} members from ${guild.name}.`);
        guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
            console.log(`${member.user.tag} (ID: ${member.id})`);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it only gave like 4 users.

Comment: That's impossible as I tested this code and it worked for me without issues. I'll edit my answer for another solution instead.

Comment: @ignshifts updated answer. Could you check please?